# Error Duplicate entry '1-11' for key 'user_image' when creating new UNIQUE index

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique, mysql-error-1062

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `userimageview` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail_view` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fullsize_view` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `point` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `everything` (`user_id`,`image_id`,`thumbnail_view`,`fullsize_view`,`point`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The index that I'm going to add:

```
ALTER TABLE `userimageview` ADD UNIQUE `user_image` (`user_id` , `image_id`)
```

Result:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-11' for key 'user_image'
```

How should I add my `UNIQUE` index?

Comment: Sounds like you have a row that violates your constraint.  `SELECT * FROM userimageview WHERE user_id = 1 AND image_id = 11`

Comment: Better yet, find all the duplicates:  `SELECT user_id, image_id, COUNT(*) AS dupes FROM userimageview GROUP BY user_id, image_id HAVING dupes > 1 ORDER BY dupes DESC`

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right @Michael. I thought that there should be a STRUCTURAL error! Please post your solution as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: We should wait 5 more minutes. Thank you anyway. I was struggling with it all night

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your newly added `UNIQUE` constraint is failing because your table already contains duplicate rows that violate it.  Locate the constraint violators with a query like the following. You won't be able to add the `UNIQUE` index as long as these rows are present.

```
SELECT
  user_id, 
  image_id, 
  COUNT(*) AS dupes
FROM userimageview
GROUP BY user_id, image_id
HAVING dupes > 1
ORDER BY dupes DESC
```